# Copying arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

In my C program I am trying to copy an array of char's to another array whilst removing the first element (element 0).

I have written:

```
char array1[9];
char array2[8];
int i, j;

for(i = 1, j = 0 ; i < 10, j < 9; i++, j++){
        array2[j] = array1[i];
}
printf(array2);
```

When I print array2, it gives me a stack overflow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you initialize for loops like that? I would just do for(i=0;i<8;i++){ array2[j] = array1[j+1]; }

Comment: Ummm, the first index of a C array is 0. The last index is size-1. So you're overflowing array2 when you assign `array2[8]`. Also, your condition with the comma operator is wrong, remember that the comma operator throws away the first value. You want `&&` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use memcpy():

```
memcpy( array2, &array1[1], 8 );
```

Thats easier.

Comment: What is O complexity of memcpy?

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:
First, when printing a string with `printf`, and working with other standard C string functions in general, your char arrays need to be null-terminated so the functions know where the string ends. You are also writing one past the end of your arrays.

Second, when using `printf`, it is almost *always* a bad idea to use the string you want to print as the format string. Use

```
printf("%s", array2);
```

instead. If you use `printf` as in the original example and array2 can be influenced by the user, then your program is likely vulnerable to a format string vulnerability.

Comment: +1 about the %s.  A printf of a generic string can provide an attack vector if the "bad guy" can provide the string.  They can put in format characters into the string and force a stack overflow and likely get their own code executed.

Comment: Or you can use `puts()` if you're not doing any formatting (though I'll admit that I usually find myself using `printf("%s", xxx)`).

Answer (score 2):

Your string isn't null-terminated, so when its printed it continues printing characters past the 8 you've allocated looking for one but runs out of stack space before then. You're also writing to one character more than you've allocated and your conditions should be "combined" with `&&` -- a `,` ignores the result of the first expression. You should also avoid using a string variable as the string formatter to `printf`.

Here's your code [fixed](http://ideone.com/mNMCl):

```
char array1[10] = "123456789";
char array2[9];
int i, j;
for(i = 1, j = 0 ; i < 10 && j < 9; i++, j++){
        array2[j] = array1[i];
}
printf("%s\n", array2);
```

You can also simplify the loop by using a single index variable `i` and indexing `array2` with `i+`. You can also remove the loop entirely by using [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/), but be aware that if `n` is less than the length of the string + 1 it won't add a null-terminator.

Comment: In C, anytime you are printing a (non-literal) string and get a stack overflow, the first thing you should check is that the string is properly nul-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `printf(array2)`, it thinks it's printing a null-terminated string.  Since there is (possibly) no `\0` in `array2`, `printf` continues on past the end of `array2`, wandering into memory it isn't supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use an extra array2 like

```
printf("%.8s",array1+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on marcog's answer: you are declaring array1 with 9 elements, 0-8, and then writing from 0-9 (10 elements). Same thing with array2.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `strcpy()` (if they're both strings!) `strcpy()` wants a pointer to the source and a pointer to the destination. If you want to skip the first element of the source array just pass `source + 1`:

```
char source[] = "ffoo";
char dest[] = "barbar";

strcpy(dest, source + 1);

// now dest is "foo" (since the ending \0 is copied too)

printf("\n%s\n", dest);
```

Comment: `strncpy` is probably better, or even `strlcpy` if available.